# Inserting .DBF Files from different folder structure with their respective FilePath using SSIS?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, sql-server-2012, ssis-2012

Am working on creating SSIS Package the does the following, so far my SSIS Package works well to insert records from '.DBF' file from one folder location ONLY (Am using Data Flow Task onto the Control Flow and OLE DB Source/Destination to read a .DBF file and get it inserted). However, am not able to figure out how to make it works with 20 sites, for example: I have 20 '.DBF' files stored in the following structure:

```
1. E:\DBF Files\Site1\Data\records.DBF
2. E:\DBF Files\Site2\Data\records.DBF
3. E:\DBF Files\Site3\Data\records.DBF
4. E:\DBF Files\Site4\Data\records.DBF
```

and so on till Site20 (here file name remain the same but the content will differ from site to another).

I have table for 'records.dbf' file in my SQL Server in the following structure:

Records Table:

```
Product_Name          Price          FilePath          FileName
---------------------------------------------------------------
```

now here, how can process these files from different sites to be stored in my records sql table with it respective FilePath using SSIS??

P.S File Names will always remain the same and the path will change "Like Site 1"

Comment: You can do it with a script task.

Comment: @TabAlleman How? can you elaborate more plz

Comment: Now that I'm looking at your question again, I'm really not sure what you're asking.  What are Column 1 & 2?   Do the file paths/names ever change, or always stay the same?

Comment: @TabAlleman Here the file names will always remain the same, only the file path will change and here the changing variable is "Site1, Site2..etc" and for the columns that what the file includes "the attributes basically"

Comment: Use a For Each Loop container, add a column for the Enumerator and store  your folder paths there. Set a mapping to a variable and then use it in an expression for path to your DBF file.

Comment: @DaveSexton - Can you provide me a snapshot or something for the same.. since am new to SSIS.

Comment: Dave is on the right track.  I don't have a snapshot handy, but try googling to learn about the ForEachLoop container in SSIS, and how to use an Expression in a flat file datasource in SSIS.  That should tell you all you need to know.

Comment: Added an answer with full explanation and screenshots

Answer (score 0):

Grab a **For Each Loop container** for the SSIS Toolbox and drag it on to the Control Flow designer.

Double click the **For Each container** to bring up the editor, click the Collection tab from the left-hand menu

[image]

Leave the **Enumerator** set at **Foreach Item Enumerator** and click the **Columns** button in the lower right.

[image]

Click the **Add** button and just go with the defaults which should be **Column 0** and **String**. Click OK to return to the previous dialog. In the new **Column 0** column add your folder paths one per row.

[image]

Next click the **Variable Mappings** tab from the left-hand menu, for the drop-down menu in the **Variable** column select **New Variable**. Again go with the defaults except for the name which in my example I have called dbf_path.

[image]

Next click OK to complete the **For Each**. Now the difficult bit for me because I don't what tasks you currently have that are working for one file. Whatever it is you have working, select it with the mouse and then drag and drop it into the **For Each container**.

For each task or tasks that need to use the file path do the following:
double click it to edit, in the left-hand menu select Expressions, then click Expressions and then click the ellipsis.

[image]

From the Property drop-down in the  **Property Expression Editor** you need to find the property that would hold the file path for this task. The names are not always obvious and can be called different things in different tasks. In my example I am using a File System Task which I think is the Source Property.

[image]

Click the ellipsis in the Expression column and add an expression that consists of your path variable concatenated a string that contains the name of your file. One thing to note is backslashes have special meanings so if your string contains any they must be escaped with a second backslash.

[image]

Now when you run the package the **For Each** will loop through each path you have defined and store it in your variable which tasks will reference.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed explanation, but here your're missing one part of question, am reading these .DBF files from the respective folder and  inserting them into one table called Records which has the same structure but with different contents

Comment: As I stated in my answer I don't know which tasks you are currently using because you don't give that detail in your question, however I have answered that point when in my answer I state that any tasks in the For Each that require the path get then to use the variable. So for example if you want to store the file path in a table the easiest way would be to insert a Derived Column Transformation task into your data flow, create a new column called FilePath and for the expression just drag in your variable.

Comment: I have already state I want to insert 20 (.DBF) files with respective FilePath to my 'Records SQL Table"  in one shot instead of writing 20 transformation to do the job. Will it be possible with ur above answer or I need to do some additional changes.?? Am using Data Flow Task onto the Control Flow and OLE DB Source/Destination to read .DBF file and get it inserted.

Comment: Yes it will - one transformation inside a For Each loop.